# Object Does not appear on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe

I am trying to add a Shape (Rectangle to the GUI), Please tell me what is wrong with my code? - The objective is to use a button to add the shape, but before I even use an ActionListener, I am trying to show the shape on the interface.

```
public class FactoryPattern extends JFrame {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ShapeFactory shapes = new ShapeFactory();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        JButton loadBtn = new JButton("Load Shapes");
        JButton sortBtn = new JButton("Sort Shapes");
        panel.add(sortBtn);
        panel.add(loadBtn);
        panel.add(shapes);

        
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display two shapes (rectangles)");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
      } 
}
class ShapeFactory extends JComponent{
       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;   
            Color color = new Color(222,222,222);
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(150, 95, 150, 150, color);
            g2d.setColor(rect1.getColor());
            rect1.drawShape(g2d);
           } 
}
```

Comment: Add some debugging to see if the `paintComponent` method is ever called, for example, print something to the console inside the method. Than you will know if it's just a visual issue, or if the method is never called.

Comment: The method is Called!

Comment: Next what is this line doing `rect1.drawShape(g2d);`? Normally you would use `g2d.draw(rect1);`

Comment: What class is the `Rectangle` from, because that does not appear to be a valid method of the normal `java.awt.Rectangle` class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html edit your question to show the imports.

Comment: 'public void drawShape(Graphics form) {
  form.fillRect(upperX, upperY, width, height);
 }'

This is the method inside Rectangle

Comment: You never give ShapeFactory a preferred size and so since it is added to a JPanel that uses a default FlowLayout, the ShapeFactory JComponent will size itself in the GUI the default size, 0, 0, and thus never display itself.

Comment: Ouch. Please don't post code in comments. If you need to show additional code, [edit] your question, show the code, and explain the code with text.

Comment: Could you show me how to give a size to the ShapeFactory please?

Comment: Simplest would be `shapes.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 640));` (or whatever size you need). Best would be to override its `public Dimension getPreferredSize()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much!!